# Pass value (yes or not) to radio button in same form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

In my  (**gravityform**) I have two fields,a radio button or checkbox and a numeric field .
i'd like to pass a value (yes or not) to the radio button, based on  the  numeric field, so if i fill this with a number less than a default value for example 10 , i get the checkbox of radio button selected with "yes" or "not".
No matters if this is possible prior or after submission.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should probably try this on your own first, before asking such a general question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an event called "keyup" according to which you can change values of the radio button. Try the following code :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js" integrity="sha256-laXWtGydpwqJ8JA+X9x2miwmaiKhn8tVmOVEigRNtP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#numbervalue").on("propertychange change keyup", function() {
        var val = $("#numbervalue").val();
        if (val > 10) {
          $("#one").prop("checked", false);
          $("#two").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
          $("#one").prop("checked", true);
          $("#two").prop("checked", false);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="">
    Number:
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="numbervalue" id="numbervalue" value="10">
    <br>
    <br>Value is more than 10 ?
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="truth" id="one" value="0" checked>No
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="truth" id="two" value="1">Yes
    <br>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A note to your solution, and "keyup" solutions in general, they do not handle mouse cut/paste events. If you paste a number in via right click + paste or cut out the current number or part of a number with right click + cut, it will not trigger the keyup event.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.. I have updated my solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic demo for what you are trying to do:

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vasejimoga/4/edit?html,js,output)

The basic idea is that you look at the value in the input field and check or uncheck the radio button accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should register an event handler for the numeric input.

Pure JS solution:

```
var radioYes = document.getElementById("choice_1_49_0"),
    radioNo = document.getElementById("choice_1_49_1"),
    valueToCheck = 10;

document.getElementById("input_1_38").addEventListener("change", function() {  
    if (+this.value > valueToCheck)
       radioYes.checked = true;
    else 
       radioNo.checked = true;  
}, false);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6a8ag1q/)

EDIT: Updated code according to your markup.

Comment: ok here is my html
[code]
<form action=""><label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_38">age</label>
<input id="input_1_38" class="small" tabindex="20" name="input_38" type="text" value="" />
<label class="gfield_label">Minor</label>
<input id="choice_1_49_0" tabindex="21" name="input_49" type="radio" value="Yes" /><label id="label_1_49_0" for="choice_1_49_0">Yes</label>
<input id="choice_1_49_1" tabindex="22" name="input_49" type="radio" value="No" /><label id="label_1_49_1" for="choice_1_49_1">No</label>
</form>
[code]

Comment: I've just updated my code according to your markup. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks, this worked, awesome!!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#input_1_38").on("propertychange change keyup", function() {
        var val = $("#input_1_38").val();
        if (val > 6575) {
          $("#choice_1_49_0").prop("checked", false);
          $("#choice_1_49_1").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
          $("#choice_1_49_0").prop("checked", true);
          $("#choice_1_49_1").prop("checked", false);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```